# How to enter a simple set of observations and randomly sample from it in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so please excuse the rudimentary nature of this question.  I have a set of known observations, say:

[Basic Distribution Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lJEp.jpg)

I'd like to enter this into R and randomly sample from this distribution as part of a larger script.  I'm familiar with reading in datasets and fitting distributions, but somehow I'm left scratching my head with this example.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: You attached a distribution. Is it your dataframe or is it summary statistics from your dataframe ?

Comment: My point is that it will not be the same implementation depending on your answer to this question

Comment: The attached distribution is my dataframe - I have no additional fidelity regarding the actual numerical observations.  My intent is to randomly sample sizes (using the attached dataframe counts as a weighting function) and feed them into a separate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image you linked to is your whole data frame and you just have counts for the different categories, you can sample from the size column using the counts as weights.

```r
data <- data.frame(measurement = c("50 or less", "50-75", "75-80"),
                   count = c(900, 86, 14))
sample(data$measurement, size = 10, replace = TRUE, prob = data$count)
```

If you have a data frame with all of your actual numerical observations, you can exclude the weights and in most cases leave replace equal to false (its default value).

```r
sample(data$measurement, size = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, @llottmanhill.  The first sample code gets me very close to what I'm after - my only issue is that I'm trying to get a numeric result (e.g., 50.5, 80.0, 61.2, etc.) with some amount of precision each time I sample. Is there a way to convert the character arrays in the measurement column (i.e., something akin to 0:50,50.1:75, and 75.1:80) to do this?

Comment: Is there a way to do it?  Yes.  However, if you just have the summary table, then you don't know anything about the distribution of measurements within each of those ranges.  Take 50 or less--are observations in that range mostly close to 50?  Are they evenly distributed between 0 and 50?  Are they frequently 0 but with a few taking positive value of 50 or less?  Can they be negative?  There's no way to know from the information provided in the table, so something that returned a numeric result would depend on making major assumptions about your data.

Comment: That said, if you just want a dataset that satisfies the constraints provided by the table, you could create a hypothetical dataset. `x <- c(sample(seq(0,50,0.1), 900, TRUE), sample(seq(50.1,75,0.1), 86, TRUE), sample(seq(75.1,80,0.1), 14, TRUE))`